# hibernate transaction will lock the row in table(MySQL)

Tags: hibernate, locking

I am using Hibernate3.2 in my DAO layer. I need to know, hibernate will do the row level lock after transaction is started. Hibernate do the lock after start the transaction or while commit the transaction? Hibernate has ability to lock the table or row?

```
Session session1=HibernateSessionFactory.currentSession();
Transaction tran1=session1.beginTransaction();

TaskFolder folder=session1.load(TaskFolder.class,2);

session.update(folder);

tran1.commit();
```

Is there any lock will happen in mysql database due to transaction or not?

Comment: I don't know a lot about MySQL, so this is just guessing, but I'd say the default transaction isolation level is a database property. Still, if it locks, it will lock when the `flush()` happens. And that will depend on you configuration...

Answer (score 0):

The `session.load()` method has an overloaded method that take a third parameter which is a `LockMode` object: `load(TaskFolder.class, 2, LockMode.UPGRADE);` for example. Just look at the possible locks and choose the one you need.